# LU Decomposition: difference between between hand calculation and solver?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, octave, lu-decomposition

I have a $3 \times 3$ matrix $A$ and have to perform the $LU$ Factorization (1)

$$ A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
1 & -1 & 3 \\
-2 & -10 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

Using row reduction, I would first substract the second row by (1/1) the first row which gives (2):

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & -3 & 0 \\
-2 & -10 & -2
\end{bmatrix}$$

I would then substract the third row by (-2/1) the first row which gives (3)

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & -6 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$$

Finally I would substract the third row by (-6/2) the second row which would give (4):

$$ \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\ 
0 & -3 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix} = U$$

with the factor found in (2) (3) and (4) I can get the matrix $U$

$$L =  \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 \\ 
1 & 1 & 0 \\
-2 & 2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

I can verify that $L \times U = A$

However when I compute `[L, U] = lu(A)` with Octave, I get 
$$ U = 
\begin{bmatrix}
-2 & -10 & -2 \\ 
0 & -6 & 2 \\
0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$ L= 
\begin{bmatrix}
-0.5 & 0.5 & 1 \\ 
-0.5 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

Here is the `octave` / `matlab` code:

```
A = [1 2 3; 1 -1 3; -2 -10 -2];
U_hand = [1 2 3; 0 -3 0; 0 0 4];
L_hand = [1 0 0; 1 1 0; -2 2 1];

L_hand * U_hand

[L, U] = lu(A)
```

How can how explain the differences? I'm probably wrong somewhere but where?

Comment: You're sure that's Octave's output?  $L$ is *not* lower triangular.

Comment: Thank you @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會. I added the code in the question. I'm probably wrong somewhere but where?

Comment: The odd output from Octave aside, you do realize that LU factorization is not unique, right?

Comment: @ecjb: I wonder if Octave is permutting as it goes. Try [l, u, p] = lu (A) and see if $p$ is a permutation result.

Comment: @amd: "LU factorization is not unique" : I suspected it but didn't know it: thanks

Comment: Thanks @Moo : indeed [l, u, p] = lu(A) proves that octave is permutting. For which sake? I don't know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't have got that for your LU decomp. I used python which uses the same LAPACK

```
import scipy.linalg
import 

A = scipy.array([[1 ,2,3],[1, -1, 3 ] ,[-2,-10,-2]])
P,L,U = scipy.linalg.lu(A)


L
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ],
       [-0.5,  1. ,  0. ],
       [-0.5,  0.5,  1. ]])

U
Out[4]: 
array([[ -2., -10.,  -2.],
       [  0.,  -6.,   2.],
       [  0.,   0.,   1.]])
```

Upon further inspection. The reference says

It's the product of the [permutation matrix and the L matrix](https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/lu.html)

> With two output arguments, returns the permuted forms of the upper and
>   lower triangular matrices, such that A = L * U. With one output
>   argument y, then the matrix returned by the LAPACK routines is
>   returned. If the input matrix is sparse then the matrix L is embedded
>   into U to give a return value similar to the full case. For both full
>   and sparse matrices, lu loses the permutation information.

Which leads to testing it in Python.

```
Atest = np.dot(P,L)

Out[2]: 
array([[-0.5,  0.5,  1. ],
       [-0.5,  1. ,  0. ],
       [ 1. ,  0. ,  0. ]])
```

Comment: thanks @RHowe, I agree that `Python` could be a good alternative but I take a class which uses `Octave` so I try to do as everybody do. Did you try the code in `octave`?

Comment: i just ran it in octave you're right. I'm looking at the documentation

Comment: updated, its the product of the permutation matrix and the L matrix. its automatically doing it.

Comment: many thanks @RHowe. Do you have a link to the reference?

Comment: https://octave.sourceforge.io/octave/function/lu.html